# How can we implement ostream function as member function of class ,and not as friend function so that i can be used as virtual function?

Tags: c++, object-oriented-analysis

I want to display the details of an object of derived class using  friend ostream& function of base class.How can we make that?How can I make member function and not a member function of class so that it can be used as virtual function and for displaying the details of object of derived class.

Comment: You can implement a function `virtual void put(std::ostream& os);` and use that in the global operator implementation override.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A stream inserter takes a stream as its first argument, so when the inserter is a member function it's a member of the stream class, not the class that you're writing. So it can't be a virtual function in your class. But it can **call** a virtual function in your class.

```
class my_class {
    virtual std::ostream& put(std::ostream& out) const {
        out << "here we go!\b";
    }
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const my_class& my_object);
};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const my_class& my_object) {
    my_object.put(out);
}
```